# Get days of week in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Had been trying to figure out a select query to display days of week such as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. I ended up with a select query displaying dates of a week,

```
select ((date_trunc('week',current_date)::date) + (i+6)) as week_date 
  from generate_Series(0,6) i;
```

Is there a way to get the result as Monday, Tuesday and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do just:

```
VALUES ('Sunday'), ('Monday'), ('Tuesday'), ('Wednesday'), ('Thursday'), ('Friday'), ('Saturday');
```

Answer (score 67):

Just use [extract](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
extract(dow from date_column::timestamp)
from whatever_table;
```

This returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday,...,6 for Saturday.

**Edit:** Or, since you apparently don't need anything that actually requires grabbing the day of week from a given date and you just want a single column with the fixed string values representing the names of the days of the week, just create a table...

Comment: Hi jack, I dont want the number values of days, Instead i need the query to return all seven days as 'Sunday''Monday' etc. Can you suggest other possibilities?

Comment: @Flourida - As I pointed out in the comment section of Edwin's answer, if you don't need any of this dynamically generated, then why are you trying to do this in SQL?  Just print out the strings `"Sunday"`,`"Monday"`, etc, and be done with it.

Comment: That prints the value in different columns. how can i get it in single column?

Comment: @Flourida - Make a table with one column.  These are fixed strings.  There's nothing that you need to dynamically generate.

Answer (score 54):

In Postgres 9 onwards there's:

`to_char(date, 'dy');`

which would return your date into the day of the week as a text value

Comment: note that `to_char()` will give you a `char` e.g. `select '|' || to_char(current_date, 'Day') || '|';` will give you `|Tuesday  |` - so you probably need/want to trim.

Answer (score 2):

The following query also works

```
select to_char((date_trunc('week',current_date)::date) + i,'Day') as wkday from generate_series(0,6) i
```

Comment: note that `to_char()` will give you a `char` e.g. `select '|' || to_char(current_date, 'Day') || '|';` will give you `|Tuesday  |` - so you probably need/want to trim.

Answer (score 1):

creates a single field array that you unnest

```
select day_of_week
from unnest(
array
  ['Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
   'Saturday']
) as day_of_week
```